# How can I play Age of Mythology on WMware Fusion with Windows 7?

Tags: emulation, age-of-mythology

Thanks to Google I found this video on youtube:

I followed the instructions that Nolnar posted - they are the same as those in the youtube video.

But now I get this error message from the AOM, telling me that the Graficcard is not supported, and will shutdown the program, leaving this note:

> 8/26/2013 7.14.1.5025

I am running VMWare for MAC OSX v10.9.1

Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Arqade!  Can you please post more information?  What platform are you running VMware Fusion on.  MacOSX, Linux, etc.  And, what version of that OS, too.  It might help people answer your question.

Comment: I am running WMware on MAC OSX Version 10.9.1 - THANKS !

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer to your question.  But, hopefully that information will help someone else to give you one!  Please also take the the time to click on the help tab and read through the tour section of the site.  It's very helpful for new posters!